# Is the eternal life unique as it is?

Tags: eternal-life

Is the eternal life unique as it is?

Can there be two or three eternal lives? Apostle John said that those who believe in Christ the Son of God have eternal life (1 John 5:13). When the fall of man had just taken place, God made sure Adam wasn't able to partake of the tree of life and, thus, start living forever (Gen. 3:22,24). Was that eternal life that was contained in the tree of life the same as the life that apostle John is talking about in his epistle?

Comment: Are you asking about the words in these two texts or about some doctrine doctrine or multiple cycles of life? I think this could be worded better but first we need to know what the question really is about. If it's about the interpretation of those two texts it might actually be better served on the [Hermeneutics](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com) site!

Comment: Or are you talking about multiple levels of eternal life, e.g. heaven (and purgatory?) and hell.

Comment: I am simply talking about life. You know, you are reading these words, you are typing some words now, you are breathing because you have life in you. If you can see through your window a green tree and some birds sitting in it, you know that the tree is green and the birds are singing, because they have life in them. Now if you happen to see a corpse of a human, or of a bird or a dry tree trunk, you will know for sure that they can't breathe or move by themselves because there is no life in them (it used to be in them, but now it's not there, i.e. that life was/is not eternal).

Comment: This question needs a substantial edit before it fits with the quality guidelines laid out by this community. Please clarify a doctrine you are asking about.

Comment: @wax - I have already clarified it in my comment above - it's a doctrine about eternal life. I don't know what further clarification is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a distinction between living forever on earth and eternal life.

Although we are not given overt and explicity details about this, it appears that the tree of life enabled Adam and Eve to live forever on earth.  Prior to the Fall, this was great.  After the Fall, however, this would have caused mankind to remain in an unredeemed body that is incapable of fully realizing the relationship with God for which we were created.  Thus, physical immortality in an unredeemed state is really an entrapment apart from the glory God desires for us to experience.

Jesus specifically defines eternal life in John 17 as the ability to know God.  This is what John was also referring to in John 20:30-31 as well as the verse you mentioned--1 John 5:13.  Eternal life is being in a relationship with God through Jesus Christ the Son.  This, again, is to be distinguished from physical immortality.

> And this is eternal life, that they know you the only true God, and
>   Jesus Christ whom you have sent. John 17:3 ESV
>
> Now Jesus did many other signs in the presence of the disciples, which
>   are not written in this book; 31 but these are written so that you may
>   believe that Jesus is the Christ, the Son of God, and that by
>   believing you may have life in his name.  John 20:30-31

If one lived forever in a physical body that is under the curse and not be able to separate from that into a glorified body, then our relationship with God would be ultimately limited.  For, as the Scripture says, when we see God face to face, then it is when we will know Him fully, as we are fully known by Him.

> For now we see in a mirror dimly, but then face to face. Now I know in
>   part; then I shall know fully, even as I have been fully known.  1
>   Corinthians 13:12 ESV

So, immortal physical life is distinct from eternal life.  The former would inhibit our relationship with God, while the latter gives us a relationship with God.

Comment: To refer to John 17: (And this is eternal life, that they know you the only true God, and Jesus Christ whom you have sent. John 17:3 ESV)

Comment: @OnesimusUnbound Thanks.  I've added the reference in the answer.  Nice catch!

Comment: @Narnian - Thank you for your answer. So, the tree of life, according to your question is the physical life then, right? "The former would inhibit our relationship with God" - I am a bit puzzled here. Why do you say inhibit? Why would then God need to give us the tree of life in the future again (Rev. 2:7)?

Comment: @brilliant Great question! The tree of life in the future will be in heaven, so that would not give physical immortality.  Eating of it in a glorified body would not inhibit our relationship with God, for that will already be fully realized at that point.

Comment: @Narnian - So what will it be needed for then?

Comment: @brilliant Again, it's not clear why the tree of life is in heaven.  Perhaps it is just there for our enjoyment.  Heaven is, after all, a place of joy.

Comment: @Narnian - Can you, please, tell me which verse tells us that the tree of life is in the heaven. I only get two verses from "Revelation" telling us that the tree of life will be in the paradise of God (Rev. 2:7) and in the New Jerusalem (Rev. 22:2), which, unless we consider the possibility of having two trees of life, means that the New Jerusalem is the paradise of God. However, the New Jerusalem is described as "coming down from the heaven" (Rev. 21:2,10) rather then "in the heaven".

Comment: @brilliant These are great questions.  In fact, the distinction between the New Jerusalem and the paradise of God is probably a great candidate for a new question here.  I guess I was not precise in my comment.  The tree of life will be in the afterlife.  I haven't really studied the particulars of where that will be.  That's why that would make another great question.